# Why do we need exclude in pom

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

Pom.xml have this elements and I am curious why do we need exclude `commons-logging` from `spring-core`? And how do it works?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
<!-- next is log4j dependencie -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen and done the similar things before, the reason is simple:

To exclude `commons-logging` library because I want to use `log4j` instead.

So you tell maven to not include the unnecessary library, and to do that use `< exclusion >`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a different version of `commons-logging` in your program than the one that is defined by `spring-core` 3.0.5.RELEASE. Check the dependecies of your program and see if there is another `commons-logging` defined.

Answer (score 0):

In the example above spring-core itself has a dependency on commons-logging so it will pull that jar into the project.  For what ever reason the user did not want the commons-logging that comes with spring-core, they may want to use another version.

It is possible to have 2 dependencies which have sub dependencies that clash with each other, although I would say this is rare. Usually excludes can be used sparingly.